# Docker and wazuh container installation

Tags: docker, docker-compose, wazuh

I am trying to install wazuh as a docker container and then i get this below error after entering docker-compose up. Please help

```
docker-compose up
[+] Running 12/12
 ⠿ Volume "single-node_filebeat_etc"             Created                                                               0.0s
 ⠿ Volume "single-node_wazuh_queue"              Created                                                               0.0s
 ⠿ Volume "single-node_wazuh_api_configuration"  Created                                                               0.0s
 ⠿ Volume "single-node_wazuh_etc"                Created                                                               0.0s
 ⠿ Volume "single-node_wazuh_logs"               Created                                                               0.0s
 ⠿ Volume "single-node_wazuh_agentless"          Created                                                               0.0s
 ⠿ Volume "single-node_wazuh_var_multigroups"    Created                                                               0.0s
 ⠿ Volume "single-node_wazuh_integrations"       Created                                                               0.0s
 ⠿ Volume "single-node_wazuh_active_response"    Created                                                               0.0s
 ⠿ Volume "single-node_wazuh_wodles"             Created                                                               0.0s
 ⠿ Volume "single-node_filebeat_var"             Created                                                               0.0s
 ⠿ Container single-node-wazuh.manager-1         Created                                                               0.1s
Attaching to single-node-wazuh.dashboard-1, single-node-wazuh.indexer-1, single-node-wazuh.manager-1
Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error mounting "/run/desktop/mnt/host/wsl/docker-desktop-bind-mounts/Ubuntu/8f7109a4f50746c8c4118dd0092c7a6ca75ad9de4a8aa814d81043cbe98a9002" to rootfs at "/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/config/certs/admin.pem": mount /run/desktop/mnt/host/wsl/docker-desktop-bind-mounts/Ubuntu/8f7109a4f50746c8c4118dd0092c7a6ca75ad9de4a8aa814d81043cbe98a9002:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/config/certs/admin.pem (via /proc/self/fd/14), flags: 0x5000: not a directory: unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
```

i tried to remove the image and added again but still same

Comment: Can you show the compose file?

Comment: Hi Tarun  how to attach the yaml file here its too big

Comment: I would like to know any solution for the issue i am facing appreciate if any one could kindly please help

Answer (score 0):

The error message that can be seen in the output of the **docker-compose up** command refers to a problem with the certificates in the Wazuh indexer container, specifically with the **admin.pem** certificate, when the container starts, it does not find said file (the certificates are generated prior to deployment and are mounted in the container through a volume).

Have you previously generated the certificates as indicated in our [documentation](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/deployment-options/docker/wazuh-container.html)? If what you are going to do is a single-node deployment, you don't have to configure anything, just run the following command from the single-node directory of the cloned repository:

```
docker-compose -f generate-indexer-certs.yml run --rm generator
```

After executing the above command you should have an output like the following:

```
Cert tool exists in Packages bucket
05/12/2022 13:46:24 INFO: Admin certificates created.
05/12/2022 13:46:24 INFO: Wazuh indexer certificates created.
05/12/2022 13:46:24 INFO: Wazuh server certificates created.
05/12/2022 13:46:24 INFO: Wazuh dashboard certificates created.
Moving created certificates to destination directory
changing certificate permissions
Setting UID indexer and dashboard
Setting UID for wazuh manager and worker
```

Once generated, run the **docker-compose up** command and the deployment should succeed.

Comment: Hi Raul,Thank you for the message i run this then i get remove-orphans flag to clean it up.
[+] Running 0/1
 ⠿ generator Error                                                                                                83.0s
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": EOF

Comment: "/run/desktop/mnt/host/wsl/docker-desktop-bind-mounts/Ubuntu/8f7109a4f50746c8c4118dd0092c7a6ca75ad9de4a8aa814d81043cbe98a9002" to rootfs at "/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/config/certs/admin.pem": mount /run/desktop/mnt/host/wsl/docker-desktop-bind-mounts/Ubuntu/8f7109a4f50746c8c4118dd0092c7a6ca75ad9de4a8aa814d81043cbe98a9002:/usr/share/wazuh-indexer/config/certs/admin.pem

Comment: I see that you are doing a WSL deployment, please, check your firewall configuration (both on the host and on the Linux instance) and if you are behind a proxy, you must add an "environment" section to the "generate-indexer-certs.yml" file, please read point number 2 of this documentation: https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/deployment-options/docker/wazuh-container.html#single-node-deployment, remember to perform a full cleanup of the deployment before generating the certificates.

Comment: If it still fails, you can try to build the image locally with the command: "docker build -t wazuh/wazuh-certs-generator:0.0.1 ." and continue with the certificates generation and the environment deployment.

Comment: It would be necessary to know more information about your environment since I see references to "docker-desktop", how are you deploying the environment?? Is it a WSL instance? Are you using the Docker Desktop app? Are you running the commands in a PowerShell terminal with administrator permissions?

Comment: Hi Raul Thank you for your reply, Yes I am using WSL instance, and i do use Powershell Terminal in Ubuntu.

Comment: Due to the lack of information about the steps that you have carried out according to the instructions that I have given, we are going to proceed to clean up the existing docker resources, please perform the following numbered steps in order.

Comment: 1. First stop and remove the containers that may exist, for this, check them using the command "docker ps -a", if there is any Wazuh container, stop it using "docker stop CONTAINER_ID" and then remove it using "docker rm CONTAINER_ID".

Comment: 2. The next step is to remove the existing volumes, they all start with "single-node_X", for this, run the command "docker volume rm $(docker volume ls --filter name=single-node -q)", if you now run the "docker volume ls" command, you should not see any reference to "single_node".

Comment: 3. The next step is to remove the images you had downloaded, to do so run the command "docker rmi (docker images "wazuh/*" -q)" (this command will remove all Wazuh images, which in the case of a single-deployment node, there should be four, the image of the certificate generator and one for each component)

Comment: 4. The last step is to delete the "single-node/config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs" folder, which is where the certificates are generated, it is important that you make sure that this folder does not exist.

Comment: 5. If in the system you only have Docker references of the deployment you are doing, you can do a general cleanup with these commands: "docker-compose down", "docker volume prune", "docker system prune -a", and "rm -rf ./config/wazuh_indexer_ssl_certs/", keep in mind that these commands will remove everything in Docker, even non-Wazuh related, so run them with caution.

Comment: After performing the five steps above, run these commands in order: "docker-compose -f generate-indexer-certs.yml run --rm generator" and "docker-compose up"